# Create extension that run a function if object is not null

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

Can I have kotlin extension function that do something like this:

```
// extension
inline fun <T : Any> T?.runIfNotNull(function: (T) -> Unit) {
    this?.let { function(it) }
}

// some function
fun doSomething(int: Int){
    // do something
}

// doSomething will be called with maybeNullInt as argument, 
// when maybeNullInt is not null
maybeNullInt?.runIfNotNull { doSomething }
```

basically, what I want is replace

```
maybeNullInt?.let{ doSomething(it) }
```

with

```
maybeNullInt?.runIfNotNull { doSomething }
```

Comment: Why do you need additional function if you can use for example `maybeNullInt?.let{}`?

Comment: basically I want to do this `maybeNullInt?.runIfNotNull { doSomething }` not this `maybeNullInt?.let{ doSomething(it) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> basically I want to do this maybeNullInt?.runIfNotNull { doSomething }

You already can with `?.let` (or `?.run`):

```
maybeNullInt?.let(::doSomething)
```

You can't write `{ doSomething }` because it would mean something quite different. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#callable-references for explanation of the `::` syntax.

If you define `runIfNotNull` you can actually use it without `?`:

```
maybeNullInt.runIfNotNull(::doSomething)
```

(does nothing if `maybeNullInt` is `null`).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating your own extension function you can use `let` function from Kotlin Standard Library:

```
maybeNullInt?.let(::doSomething)
```

`::` -  in Kotlin we use this operator to reference a function by name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Either use function reference

```
maybeNullInt?.runIfNotNull(::doSomething)
```

or pass a parameter in a lambda

```
maybeNullInt?.runIfNotNull { doSomething(it) }
```